# Upload and Download multiple Files single or multi thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, http, request

I want to download thousands of images from a remote server and then upload them to another remote server using Python over HTTP requests. Do I use only one thread so that each image is downloaded or uploaded individually or multiple threads so that multiple images are downloaded or uploaded parallel? And what is the maximum number of threads I should use for this at the same time? As many as I can?

Comment: This really depends on the servers you are downloading/uploading to. If they are your own servers that you know can handle lots of traffic all at once then go ahead and use as many threads as possible. If they are not your servers you may need to determine any rate or traffic limits to these servers, and only spin up as many threads as the limits allow. In theory there is no reason not to use as many threads as possible, but in practice it can cause servers to crash or block your requests.

Comment: Check out: [Multithreaded File Copying in Python](https://superfastpython.com/multithreaded-file-copying/)